# Converting Unicode to string and String to Unicode in Java

Tags: java, string, unicode

How can I convert this string: 
This string contains the unicode character unicodetoString("\u0064") and string to unicode like stringtounicode("a")?

```
public static String GetUnicode(String str_code) {          
String hexCode = Integer.toHexString(str_code.codePointAt(0)).toUpperCase();        
    String hexCodeWithAllLeadingZeros = "0000" + hexCode;
    String hexCodeWithLeadingZeros = hexCodeWithAllLeadingZeros
    .substring(hexCodeWithAllLeadingZeros.length() - 4);
    hexCodeWithLeadingZeros = "\\u" + hexCodeWithLeadingZeros;
    System.out.println("Unicode " + hexCodeWithLeadingZeros);
    return hexCodeWithLeadingZeros;
}
```

Comment: Strings have an encoding, which may be unicode or something else.  "Unicode to String" implies that either unicode is a data type like string is, or that string is a character encoding like unicode is.  As it stands, your question is nonsensical.  (It might help to know that java strings internally use utf-16.  Is that what you mean?)

Comment: `public static String GetUnicode(String str_code) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  //StringBuilder hexcode = Integer.toHexString(str_code.codePointAt(0)).toUpperCase();
  String hexCode = Integer.toHexString(str_code.codePointAt(0)).toUpperCase();  
  String hexCodeWithAllLeadingZeros = "0000" + hexCode;
  String hexCodeWithLeadingZeros = hexCodeWithAllLeadingZeros
  .substring(hexCodeWithAllLeadingZeros.length() - 4);
  String myunicode = "\\u" + hexCodeWithLeadingZeros;
//  System.out.println("\\u" + hexCodeWithLeadingZeros);
  return myunicode;
 }`

Comment: using this code i convert string to unicode but when i pass to unicodetostring(myunicode) it will cant change but if i pass statically in unicodetoString("\u0064") then i get answer              `unicodetoString(myunicode){try {
   byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
   string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
   System.out.println("in byte conversion" + string);
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }}`

Comment: String is a stream of characters. Each character is represented by unique number, called unicode. Methods for converting this number to binary is called encoding.

Comment: so you are not converting a string to unicode, unicode is a way to represent character. saying converting string to unicode makes no sense.

Comment: @gigadot how? and why? pls explain

Comment: i just did in my first comment.

Comment: @umarmansuri Please add that code to your original question. It is not readable in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Convert a unicode to string use

[StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi).unescapeJava(unicodeString)